# How To Fix Rendering of use xltxtra usepackage With XeLaTeX?

Tags: xetex, amsmath, output, rendering, xltxtra

[image]

How To Fix Rendering of use xltxtra usepackage With XeLaTeX?

Comment: It would be easier to debug if you provided an example code, The usual recommendation is not to load `xlxtra` these days it was just a utility package loading other packages not all of which are useful or recommended currently.

Comment: i'am use XeTeXupwardsmode

Comment: That is a xetex primitive it does not depend on any package.

Answer (score 2):

[image]

This is unrelated to any package use. You can set the mode back to 0 in math, for example

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\XeTeXupwardsmode=1
\everymath{\XeTeXupwardsmode=0 }
\begin{document}

 111 xxx $\sqrt{a+b}$ xxx
 222 xxx $\sqrt{a+b}$ xxx
 333 xxx $\sqrt{a+b}$ xxx
 444 xxx $\sqrt{a+b}$ xxx
 555 xxx $\sqrt{a+b}$ xxx

\end{document}
```

Comment: David Carlisle- Hello? thank you so much. Mathematical equation has been solved. But the layout of the table turned to the wrong side.

Comment: @Bat-erdeneAltangerel that is why questions should always include a test document:-) You had not mentioned a table until now.  Simplest is probably to use `\begin{tabular}[t]` to avoid the hidden math in the table setup.